# Execute a program on a remote server from a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application and I've been asked to add functionality to execute a console app located on a remote server.  This is my first cut solution to be called from a Controller method,  which comes from various StackOverflow threads:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\PsTools");
info.FileName = @"C:\PsTools\psexec.exe";
info.Arguments = @"\\" + MYSERVER + @"  C:\Misc_Apps\AppGenerator\AppGenerator.Console.exe";
info.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

I don't think this approach will work because there is no guarantee that there will be a folder C:\PsTools.  There is also the question of authenticating this on the remote server.
Is such functionality feasible?  If so, is this the right approach?  If not, can someone please point me to a suitable approach.

EDIT: Please ignore the security implications - for the moment I'm interested in whether it can be done.

Comment: Seems like a huge security hole....

Comment: It's on an Intranet but for the moment, I'm mainly interested in whether it can be done.  I'll worry about the security implications later.

Comment: Your question is so broad and lacks so much detail that the answer is yes with a lot of leeway to turn into a no. For one you're currently not using anything that has to do with PowerShell. The PS in psexec has nothing to with [powershell](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-server/psexec-explainer-mark-russinovich)

Comment: Apologies - I assume Psexec stood for PowerShell exec.  Question now amended.  Really, I'm looking for a possible approach, not a critique of my knowledge or lack of it.

Comment: @Edwardo you shouldn't proceed with this attempt without understanding the implications. `Please ignore the security implications` impossible, because that's exactly what will prevent this from working. You're trying to execute `psexec` using the application pool account, to connect to a remote computer and execute something there. This would only work if the app pool used a domain account with enough permissions on the remote machine to do what you want.

Comment: @Edwardo Powershell is built with .NET which means you can actually create a Powershell pipeline in code and execute scripts, either on the local machine or remotely. This way you won't have to allow the app pool account to execute processes. You could create a Powershell script block that accepts parameters instead of concatenating strings to reduce the chance of script injection. That's [explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/creating-remote-runspaces?view=powershell-7.2)